# How to know where to put the threshold signal of an op-amp comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am really confused on where to place my signals on amp. So basically what I want is a comparator that when a Vsignal exceeds Vthreshold the output would read HIGH on the GPIO. My Op-amp is [TLV7041](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv7041.pdf?ts=1600030136597&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV7041) open-drain type op amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcAa9C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is my attempt at the circuit, since my op-amp is an open-drain type makes a bit tricky for me since an "ON" will read a 0v on my GPIO. When Vsignal is below Vthres the op amp should be "ON" so that the GPIO would read 0v and when Vsignal is above Vthres the op amp should be "OFF" so that the GPIO would read 5V. I am having a hard time grasping the concept of which of the inputs is the typical reference

Comment: FYI, it's generally a bad idea to use an opamp as a comparator if you have a slow-moving signal.  The problem is the opamp gets in an inbetween state while changing and can burn out.  Far better to use an actual comparator IC as they'll have some hysteresis in their trigger.  If your signal is "fast" it'll probably be fine.  First time I learned this I was repairing a product with a temperature-controlled fan.  The designer used an opamp to check the value of a thermistor, smoked the opamp in service.

Comment: @KyleB thank you for that advice i will keep that in mind when using op-amps. The Op-amp i used does have an internal hysteresis so i think i will be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy.

If V<sub>IN+</sub> > V<sub>IN-</sub> the output switches high.

To reverse the output logic levels just switch the inputs.

Don't forget your op-amp decoupling capacitor across the supply pins.

Comment: This is where my confusion comes from, _If VIN+ > VIN- the output switches high._ are you talking about my circuit or op-amps in general? because an ON open drain op-amp means LOW  reading on the GPIO.

Comment: I'm talking about op-amps in general and this one in particular. See Figure 2 in your datasheet. To be more clear: if Vin- > Vin+ the output will switch low which will connect the drain to the source - i.e., pull the output to 0 V. I suggest that talking about output ON or OFF will lead to confusion - hence I use high and low.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that good sir, i can finally have peace of mind that i made the correct circuit.